# How to convert 16 bit PCM data to voltage values in Android

Tags: android, android-audiorecord, android-hardware

I am trying to calculate the db value of sound coming from the microphone in Android.
I have used Audio Record class to get 16 bit PCM data from the microphone.

```
      //init a recorder instance
      recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,ECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);                                   

      recorder.startRecording();

    // and then read 16 bit PCM data
      recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
```

The range of values for this data is from -32768 to 32767 (signed 2^16).

I believe that these are the quantized values.But I would like to find out what the corresponding voltage value is.What is the voltage value range for a microphone
in android ? Is it more or less the same for all smartphones?

Eg : Say the microphone output is 0 to +5 V then 32767 corresponds to +5 V DC .

Comment: After searching through the net, I found out that the amplitude values depend on the ADC used in the device and not on the microphone itself.